# how to set english as default language in facebook sdk login android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK to login in my android app. It always showing the login page in Local language. I want it to be ENGLISH. I tried the below link of Facebook documentation, but couldn't able to figure it out.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization

Comment: What is the default language of the device?

Comment: English is the default language of my device. But the login page is coming as Kannada(Local language)

Answer (score 1):

In Graph API, the language is set using locale parameter. 
So you can use the following graph API for changing the language of login page,

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?
client_id={APP_ID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URL}&locale=en_US
```